# IIS configuration for local website that will be published

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis

A local website will be developed on a local machine in Visual Studio and then deployed to IIS express on a remote server. Is it worth adding the website to the local machine's IIS express for development purposes, or is Visual Studio sufficient to handle the development and publishing to the remote IIS Server?

Comment: When you open and debug a web application in VS, it is very likely that you are using IIS Express already. So I wonder what exactly you wanted to learn.

Comment: If you check visual studio debug configuration, then you should notice that VS provide various kind of debug solution including IIS express and kestrel,azure. You don't have to install IIS express manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual studio have comes with an own limited set of `IIS express` for development purpose. You don't need to deploy your website to IIS on local machine. Also IIS express has all the ability required for developing and debugging an application

You can also find out the difference between the two on microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/introduction-to-iis-express/iis-express-overview#iis-express-and-iis)